# v3.0: PUT /addresses/delivery returns 401

Tags: http-status-code-401, spartacus-storefront

While upgrading from 2.1 to 3.0, we noticed that the `PUT /users/current/carts/{validId}/addresses/delivery?addressId={validId}` returns `401 Unauthorized`.

In `occ-checkout-delivery.adapter.ts` the method `setAddress()` is running the request.
This method was not overwritten on our side.

Is there anyting we are missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix.

Had to adjust the endpoint configuration for a particular key:

```
setDeliveryAddress: 'orgUsers/${userId}/carts/${cartId}/addresses/delivery',
```

Instead of `users/`, we had to use `orgUsers/` due to our back end implementation.